# Get coordinate index from array on GeoJSON data in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have GeoJSON data with LineString feature type. I will display this data using `L.geoJson()` function. The data has properties of rotation for each coordinate. I want to create a marker with that rotation properties for each coordinates. This is my geojson data.

```json
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Track of bus 699",
        "times": [
            "2019-11-23 10:51:06",
            "2019-11-23 10:52:05",
            "2019-11-23 10:53:05",
            "2019-11-23 10:54:04",
            "2019-11-23 10:55:05",
            "2019-11-23 10:56:05",
            "2019-11-23 10:57:05",
            "2019-11-23 10:58:05",
            "2019-11-23 10:59:05",
            "2019-11-23 11:00:06"
        ],
        "rotation": [
            0,
            0,
            15,
            15,
            20,
            25,
            35,
            45,
            55,
            60
        ]
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -4.4214296,
                36.73835
            ],
            [
                -4.422104,
                36.737865
            ],
            [
                -4.4229302,
                36.73773
            ],
            [
                -4.4235334,
                36.735817
            ],
            [
                -4.4222927,
                36.73413
            ],
            [
                -4.4218254,
                36.732475
            ],
            [
                -4.4213734,
                36.72983
            ],
            [
                -4.420156,
                36.73
            ],
            [
                -4.419239,
                36.730686
            ],
            [
                -4.417272,
                36.732136
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I am confused how to get the index of each coordinate so that I can get rotation data based on that index.

This is my code. I used [Leaflet.RotatedMarker](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker) plugin for rotate the marker

```js
var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
                    return new L.marker(latLng, {
                        icon: icon,
                        rotationAngle: feature.properties.rotation[index]
                    });
            }
        });
```

I have tried using `Array.findIndex()` and return the index if it has the same latitude and longitude coordinate, but there's a possibility that the data have the same coordinate with different rotation.

And I have tried using loop as well, but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your GeoJSON data Feature has currently a LineString geometry type, so the Leaflet `pointToLayer` option will not be used.

Assuming that your times and rotation properties are ordered exactly like the successive coordinates pairs of your LineString, you could convert it first into a list of Point geometries, with their associated time and rotation:

```js
// Convert LineString into list of Points
const times = originalGeoJsonFeature.properties.times;
const rotations = originalGeoJsonFeature.properties.rotation;
const coordinatePairs = originalGeoJsonFeature.geometry.coordinates;
const pointList = [];

for (let i = 0; i < coordinatePairs.length; i += 1) {
  pointList.push({
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
      time: times[i],
      rotation: rotations[i]
    },
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: coordinatePairs[i]
    }
  });
}
```

Now if you feed this list to Leaflet GeoJSON factory, the `pointToLayer` option will be used, and each Feature will contain its own time and rotation properties:

```js
var layer = L.geoJson(pointList, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
                    return L.marker(latLng, {
                        icon: icon,
                        rotationAngle: feature.properties.rotation
                    });
            }
        });
```